# Do you need the fully synced node before sending a transaction to the network?

Tags: go-ethereum, transactions, blockchain, synchronization

I'm trying to create a wallet locally. I can create an externally owned account using geth that is connected to a local test chain. Now I would like to "push" that account to the real blockchain. Does my geth node need to be fully synced (either fast or regular) in order to send that Tx to the network?